# Add space after first character of a string

Tags: jquery

I want to add a space to the first character of a string using jquery.

For example, I have a number `"92030"` and I want to replace it with `"9 2030"`

Is there a simple way to do it with jquery ?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. I also suggest you tag this `javascript` instead of `jquery`, as there's really no need to do this overly complicated and it can be achieved in vanilla JS.

Comment: if any of the answers below helped you out, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "92030"
var position = 1
var newStr = [str.slice(0, position), str.slice(position)].join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to just use plain javascript to do what you need. Like this:

```
var originalString = "92030";
var newString = originalString.slice(0, 1) + " " + originalString.slice(1);
```

Info on the javascript string slice method can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need Jquery to do that you could use javascript, try this:

```
var str="92030";
str=str.charAt(0)+" "+str.substr(1)
```

more js/jquery functions and examples can be found [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/jquery-string-functions.html)